# How to have cntlm configuration per user?

Tags: configuration, proxy, authentication

This tutorial http://zipizap.wordpress.com/tag/cntlm/ suggests configuring cntlm using the file `etc/cntlm.conf`. It works great, but it means that all users logged to the machine will be using the same password. Is it possible to have the username and password configured for each user?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe by using `-c` flag ? And call in `.profile`:

```
/usr/sbin/cntlm -c ~/cntlm.conf
```

if several users are connected at the same time, you may change the listening port...